# Compile time processing of parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I have to eat some data from two data channels into two queues. Data eaten from each particular channel has to be written to its respective queue.

Thus I have a function :

```
void eatData(channel c, channel id)
{
   while (true)
   {
      if (channelid == 1)
      {
         write to queue 1;
      }
      else 
      {
         write to queue 2;
      }
   }
}
```

Notice the `while` loop 
I am polling for data and the application is **very**, *very* time sensitive. 
Is there a way of getting rid of those `if` conditions without writing two different functions  like this:

```
void eatDataFromChannelOneAndWriteToQueueOne()
void eatDataFromChannelTwoAndWriteToQueueTwo()
```

Can templates be used to solve this?

Comment: If `channelid` is not deterministically known at compile time, there is nothing the compiler can do. However, do not make false assumptions: modern CPUs can optimize branches very well. Compile, profile and see if that is an issue. Don't even think about optimizing before proving an optimization is needed.

Comment: Why don't you just move the `if` outside the loop, so it only executes once?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have done. Duplicated the while loop for each channel id

Comment: What is the `while` loop for?

Comment: Poll data from a place

Comment: What is the type of `channel`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 It is a udp socket.

Comment: @Wildling I mean what is its declared type? `int`, `char`, `enum`? Is it possible that it can be used as a constant expression?

Comment: If you used an array or vector of queues, you would not need to check for channel numbers.  Use the channel number as an index into the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess templates would help you, such as:

```
template<int>
struct QueueSelector
{
    static YourQueue& Queue; 
};

template<int CH>
YourQueue& QueueSelector<CH>::Queue = queue2;

template<>
YourQueue& QueueSelector<1>::Queue = queue1;

template<int CH>
void eatData()
{
    processing with QueueSelector<CH>::Queue
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this code is *time sensitive*, I suggest you use a `std::vector` of queues:

```
static std::vector<Queue_Type> data_container(MAXIMUM_CHANNELS);

void Collect_Data(const& Datum d,
                  unsigned int channel_number)
{
  data_container[channel_number].insert_value(d);
}
```

The code above is using the `std::vector` constructor that specifies the initial number of elements for the vector.  Having a vector dynamically resize is a waste of time.  Also, the fixed initial size allows the vector to be treated as an array without the need to resize.

For circular queues, I recommend using capacities that are powers of 2 so that you can use binary AND operation instead of modulo.  We made this change and our performance increased dramatically, especially since our processor does not have any division or modulo instructions.

**Edit 1:**
If your issue is reading from multiple ports, then you stick the assignment into a forever loop:

```
void Read_Multiple_Ports(void)
{
  unsigned int channel_number = 0;
  while (true)
  {
    const Datum d = Read_Channel(channel_number);
    data_container[channel_number].insert_value(d);
    ++channel_number;

    // Use if statement rather than modulo
    // because modulo (division) may be more time
    // expensive than a jump.
    // If the number of channels is a power of 2,
    //    this could be replaced by an arithmetic AND
    //    to mask the value.
    if (channel_number >= MAXIMUM_CHANNELS)
    {
      channel_number = 0;
    }
  }
}
```